# Check incoming answer with answer in array object

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I created a function to check my answer. However, When I click on the correct answer, the display message say it is the wrong answer. I have been at this for hours. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

function to check answer:

```
function checkAnswer(answer) {
    let correctAnswer = questionArray[currentQuestion].answer;
    if (answer !== correctAnswer) {
        notCorrect();

    } else {
        isCorrect();
    }
    count = 0;
    if (currentQuestion < lastQuestion) {
        currentQuestion++;
        showQuestion();
    } else {
        clearInterval(startTime);
        quizScore();
    }
}
```

function to call based on answer:

```
function isCorrect() {
    score++;
    displayMessage.textContent = 'Correct';
    document.querySelector('.btn-option').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}
function notCorrect() {
    displayMessage.textContent = 'Wrong';
    document.querySelector('.btn-option').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

Comment: Did you check, if the correct value for `answer` is passed into the function? Did you check whether te correct element from `questionArray` is accessed? What data type does `answer` have, what datatype does `questionArray[index].answer` have?

Comment: NVM, I am following JS and Java question get confused :D

Comment: Why you did not provided `questionArray`?

Comment: !==  should be replace with !=

Comment: @nobalG Maybe, but you should also explain, why.

Comment: Also simplify (DRY): `let isCorrect = questionArray[currentQuestion].answer === answer; displayMessage.textContent = isCorrect ? 'Correct' : 'Incorrrect'; document.querySelector('.btn-option').classList.toggle('correct',isCorrect); score+= isCorrect : 1 : 0;`

Comment: @derpirscher because in the comparison statement , he is comparing whether the references are pointing to the same object or not, however he is more likely interested in the value which can be done by !=

Comment: @nobalG JavaScript compares objects by identity whether you use `!=` or `!==`, it never compares them by contents. It only makes a difference when there might be type juggling.

Comment: @Barmar Thankyou for the comment, can you please provide me some source or the keyword I should search with, because I am kind of confused now.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness @nobalG

Answer (score 0):

The error may occur in

```
function checkAnswer(answer) {
    let correctAnswer = questionArray[currentQuestion].answer;
    if (answer !== correctAnswer) {
        notCorrect();
```

And *may* be caused by a discrepancy in questionArray between what `questionArray[currentQuestion]` *is* and what you *want it to be.*

This is just a supposition, since we can't see the contents of questionArray. However,
suppose:

questionArray contains `{"what's the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?", "what is the capital of Assyria?", "what is your favorite color?"}`

and the answers are `{"blue", "African or European?", "Ashur", "yellow"}` .
It appears you must be incrementing currentQuestion, most likely in a for loop- correct? If so, the value may be off or the arrays may be misaligned.

suppose:

currentQuestion is 0, so "what's the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?" is displayed. You answer, "African or European?", but `questionArray[currentQuestion].answer` may retrieve the answer "blue", blue being the first answer ([0]) in the hypothetical array of answers.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Cole Henrich. My own test below shows that the code is working properly when `answer !== correctAnswer` is false (when the answer is correct).

```js
var questionArray=[{'answer':'one'},{'answer':'two'}];
var currentQuestion=0;
function checkAnswer(answer) {
    let correctAnswer = questionArray[currentQuestion].answer;
    if (answer !== correctAnswer) {
        console.log('notCorrect();');

    } else {
        console.log('isCorrect();');
        
    }
}
checkAnswer('one');
```